# Why on "poweroff" an instance is terminated?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm surprised to see that after "poweroff" an instance is terminated and there is (currently) no way to restore to last state. It appears that the only option is to create a new VM instance from a snapshot (not last state), thus suboptimal and annoying.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected in Google Compute Engine and it's mention in the [public documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#terminate) 
However you can use the same disk to create a new instance. To do this, delete the instance without deleting the disk, and use the existing disk to create a new instance